# STL and Regular Expression

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stl

I'm trying to write a string parser that uses the standard library  methods in C++.  I want to parse out of an incoming string substrings that end with a newline or a ';'.  I keep getting exceptions from the regex object that I create.  My pattern is:

```
string pattern = "(.+[\\n\\r;])";
regex cmd_sep(pattern);
```

I've tried it with and without the regex_constants::extended or basic flags.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Intel compiler (13) on Debian 7.

Comment: regex probably isn't yet supported by your compiler. gcc also lacks this so far

Comment: Just a note, not an answer. You are probably using `libstdc++` that comes with gcc. Bear in mind that the `regex` class hasn't really been usable below gcc 4.8.

Comment: you can use the <regex.h> lib for C.

Comment: Catch the exception in the debugger -- that will at least give you a good hint as to what the error is

Answer (score 0):

You'd better post your error message, if you are using boost library. It is possible you've missed `boost::regex` tag.

Try this

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string pattern = "(.+[\\n\\r;])";
    static const boost::regex cmd_sep(pattern);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using boost in other parts of the program but not for regular expressions.  I'm using the stl regex.

Comment: regex is now part of standard C++, so no need for boost one except compilers where regex is missing or broken (e.g. gcc 4.6)